# Error Searching Sharepoint via CMIS using C#

Tags: c#, cmis, dotcmis

We are creating an application in C# that uses CMIS to query remote repositories (Sharepoint, alfresco, etc.).  My colleague set up the service references and we're able to connect and retrieve basic information.  My part is to implement searching using the DiscoveryService.query.  The issue is that the service that was represented in C# doesn't match the service documentation (found at http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/os/cmis-spec-v1.0.html#_Toc243905469).

Apparently when generating the service, an additional parameter is added at the end of the parameter string (XmlAttribute[] anyAttr) for DiscoveryServicePortClient.query.

I've searched high and low over the web and can't find a single instance of this issue.

Have you been successful in integrating CMIS w/ C# and searching the remote repository?  If so, how did you create your service references and what did you pass in as your parameters?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as not only is my head hurting, but there's a huge hole in the wall where I've been banging it for the past two days.  (If there's add'l information needed, just ask and I'll add it to this post.)

Comment: I actually have a passing familiarity with CMIS (I know - I'm the one in 1000... ;)) ... and I'd strongly encourage you to look at a RESTful implementation.  IMHO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache Chemistry DotCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html) is a .Net client library for CMIS.
If you don't want use it, you can at least have a look at the source code.

Comment: Thanks.  I checked that out as well and am now looking at implementing it.